# C# MVC how to control visibility of asp:content in child page by adding Visibility property value dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to control the visibility of an `<asp:content>...</asp:content>` block in child MVC child page. To do so I tried the the following snippet of code

`<asp:Content runat="server" ID="contentSearchControl" Visible="<%=Html.Raw(!Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice) %>" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphGlobalSearchControl"></asp:Content>`

but getting this message:

> This is not scriptlet. Will be outputted as plain text.

Is there any way to do that without using Client Script or any intermediate handler?

Comment: That appears to be asp webforms not mvc.

Comment: Do you have a need to check on the server side? Typically adapting to mobile screens is now done with client side (css/js) code / templates.

Comment: Yes, I need to check on server side because on slower internet speed at times things are not disappearing or even the page is taking long time to load leaving users confused